# why Asp.net Core can not read Ajax parameters?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jquery-plugins

I'm using Asp.net MVC Core and Jquery Ajax to make inset into my database.

The problem summary
I can't read parameters in Home-Controller's Action. That means I can successfully execute the Ajax plugin and I access Home controller without any problem using trace point, but passed values "Vals" can not be retrieved.

I’ve tried to
make a Jquery plugin with Ajax block to send JSON string to the Home-Controller

**JQuery plugin**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.CallSqlServer = function (URL, JsonVal)
    {
        var vals = JSON.stringify(JsonVal);
        var msg;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: URL,
                    data: vals,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        msg = data.msg;
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        msg = "Error occured!!";
                    }
                });
        return msg;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**I call it like this**

```
    $('#btninsert').click(function () {
        var Student = {
            ID: '10001',
            Name: 'Shashangka',
            Age: 31
        };
        $('#btninsert').CallSqlServer("/Home/Index/",Student);
    });
```

**Home-Controller => action Index**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index(string vals)
{
    return View(vals);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The data should be a key value pair representing the URL query param and value:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.CallSqlServer = function (URL, JsonVal)
    {
        var vals = JSON.stringify(JsonVal);
        var msg;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: URL,
                    data:{
                       "vals": vals
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        msg = data.msg;
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        msg = "Error occured!!";
                    }
                });
        return msg;
    }
})(jQuery);
```